A correspondence between pairs of isogenies and representation numbers
This is a question from this paper about a correspondence between representation numbers of quadratic forms, and pairs of isogenies between elliptic curves.
Let $(L, Q)$ be a quadratic space over a ring $R$. For a quadratic form $F$ on $R^m$, define the representation number $R_L(F)$ as the cardinality of the set $$\{(f_i) \in L^m : Q(x_1 f_1 + \cdots + x_m f_m) = F(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \text{ for all } x \in R^m\}.$$
For a basis $\{b_i\}$ of $L$, define the diagonal of $Q$ with respect to $\{b_i\}$ to be the $n$-tuple $(Q(b_i))_i$.
The following is a quote from the paper linked above:

Such pairs $(f_1, f_2)$ correspond to representations of positive definite quadratic forms $Q(x_1, x_2) = \deg(x_1 f_1 + x_2 f_2)$, hence $$\# \{(f_1, f_2) \in \operatorname{Hom}(E, E') : \operatorname{deg} f_i = m_i\} = \sum_{Q > 0,\ \operatorname{diag} Q = (m_1, m_2)} R_{\operatorname{Hom}(E, E')}(Q).$$

Here $E$ and $E'$ are elliptic curves with complex multiplication, which correspond to an intersection point of the modular polynomials $\phi_{m_1}$ and $\phi_{m_2}$.
The way this is stated, and the fact that the rest of this paper is quite accessible, makes me think that the above correspondence is either "well-known," or trivial, but I have not encountered this before and don't see at all why it is true.
Can someone provide either a reference, or a proof/explanation of this correspondence?

This is very classical and probably goes back to Kronecker, I seem to remember it being mentioned in Lang's book on modular functions. Also, you probably need one of $E$ and $E'$ to have $j \neq 0,1728$. The basic idea is to compose one isogeny with the dual of the other. Now use that this must be an endomorphism of $E$ which must be $a +b \psi$ where the CM order is $\mathbb{Z}[\psi]$ - now take its norm.

The contents of the linked paper are also at least closely related to Hirzebruch's paper "Kurven auf den Hilbertschen Modulflächen und Klassenzahlrelationen" where similar claims are proved

Also posted to (and answered on) MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/478069/a-correspondence-between-pairs-of-isogenies-and-representation-numbers
